# How do I get the "What the...?" achievement in Cities Skylines?

Tags: achievements, cities-skylines

In the "Natural Disasters" DLC for Cities Skylines are some new Steam achievements. One of them is `What the...? - Experience a special disaster`. I tried several things and messed around with disasters but wasn't able to figure it  out. My research was unsuccessful.

Can somebody tell me how to achieve this? Any answers welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was interestingly hard to find since usually achievement guides are all over the place. However, according to [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/CitiesSkylines/comments/5gg8k7/whats_a_special_disaster/) **you have to experience a "Chirpnado".**

According to Reddit user wasmic:

> It's the chirpnado. It has a very, very low chance of occuring. 3/703 - or 0.42 % - of all disaster will be chirpnados.

I wasn't able to find exactly what this disaster will do but, keep a look out for tornadoes sporting little blue birds.

Comment: I guess that's why it's called a special disaster and not a natural disaster.